# TypeError at /snippets/1/

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am following  [wsvincent](https://wsvincent.com/official-django-rest-framework-tutorial-beginners-guide/)  django rest framewok tutorial. I have done everything thats written there but when I run localhost/snippets/1/ it raises the following exception

TypeError at snippets/1/

**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.

Kindly help if you know whats wrong.

localhost/snippets runs fine. Here is the traceback.

http://dpaste.com/00B8VHB

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from pygments.lexers import get_all_lexers
from pygments.styles import get_all_styles

# Create your models here.
LEXERS = [item for item in get_all_lexers() if item[1]]
LANGUAGE_CHOICES = sorted([(item[1][0], item[0]) for item in LEXERS])
STYLE_CHOICES = sorted((item, item) for item in get_all_styles())

class Snippet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    code = models.TextField()
    linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python', max_length=100)
    style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Snippet, LANGUAGE_CHOICES, STYLE_CHOICES

class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields=('id','title','code','linenos','language','style',)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import SnippetSerializer
from .models import Snippet
# Create your views here.

class SnippetSerializer(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class=SnippetSerializer

class SnippetDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class=SnippetSerializer
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
path('snippets/',views.SnippetSerializer.as_view()),
path('snippets/<int:pk>/',views.SnippetDetail.as_view()),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

Comment: The code you've shown here is correct, and wouldn't give that error. Are you sure that is the actual definition of SnippetSerializer?

Comment: Well, according to the tutorial it should be that way.

Comment: Yes, that is what I said; I was asking if you're sure that is the code you are actually using.

Comment: Yes I thats the code I am using. I even copy pasted that part (after reading your comment) to be double sure. Still doesn't work.

Comment: After closely looking at the code I have realized I made a small mistake. In the views.py I kept the class based view's name as SnippetSerializer . May be that was creating a problem. When I used SnippetList in place of SnippetSerializer, It worked like a charm. Thanks for your help though.